# Regular Expression to select only a word and not a word containing those letters

Tags: php, regex

A user inputs `"California city ca"`
If a state is found in input, state is saved like so

```
$state_code = find_state_code_input($full_location); //$state_code = "ca"
```

And I have the following function which finds the first match of a pattern and replaces it with some other value

```
function str_replace_first($find, $replaceTo, $content) {
    $find = '/'.preg_quote($find, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($find, $replaceTo, $content, 1);
}
```

If there was a state found I remove it from the original full string

```
if (!empty($state_code))
    $full_location = str_replace_first($state_code, "", $full_location);
  //$full_location = "lifornia city ca"
```

However output is `"lifornia city ca"` how could I go about this so that only the word `"ca"` is deleted and not other words containing those letters? Even in cases where user input is only `"ca"` I'm not as experienced with regular expressions some help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Try:

```
\bca\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/A6BKRo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use $:

```
    $full_location = "california city ca";
    $state_code = 'ca';

    $find = '/'.preg_quote($state_code).'$/';
    if (!empty($state_code))
        $full_location = preg_replace($find, '', $full_location, 1);

    echo $full_location;
```